# Building a MakeCode Package

Tags: adafruit, makecode

I have been using this site for reference:
https://makecode.com/packages/getting-started

I'm working with the Adafruit Circuit Playground Makecode:
https://makecode.adafruit.com/

I've built my custom blocks and I'm ready to upload to Github (step 2). However, I am unable to complete the Extensions > Github Login step. I am not finding this as an option when I go to the Extensions page.

Does anyone know how to connect my Github account with the Adafruit's Makecode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This feature has not yet rolled out to all MakeCode editors. We've just pushed out a [new beta for the Adafruit Circuit Playground Express](https://makecode.adafruit.com/beta). You should be able to log in from the extensions dialog. Let me know if it works for you!

There is now also [a blog post](https://makecode.com/blog/github-packages) describing the feature in more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

So, it looks like new procedures / instructions were released: https://makecode.com/packages/getting-started

I've been able to get my Github account and Makecode connected by following the instructions.
I've imported an existing repository and I've imported a new repository. Both times, I am getting 422 errors in the DAL.D.TS file that I am not able to fix. This is occurring immediately with the default files that are created (before I add any of my own content).

It appears to be a problem with the default files. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: The dal.d.ts issue is now solved. If it occurs to anyone, remove the dal.d.ts manually from pxt.json.